# AngluarJS binding JSON data to Form

Tags: angularjs

I'm planing to setup a mechanism like this:
1) Request the Server for a JSON object
2) The JSON Object contains a structure like this

```
{"type":"address","fields":[{"name":"street"},{"name":"city"}]}
```

Based on this object a form shall be created with two input fields (street and city) and shall furthermore bound to an angularJS model.

```
$scope.formData = {"type":"address","fields":[{"name":"street","value":"Main Street"},{"name":"city","value":"NYC"}]}
```

Is this approach realizable with AngularJS? 
I want to dynamically build a form (or better say the input elements bound to AngularJS model) from a JSON object and bind a model to that form.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I unterstand you correctly you can just bind your object directly: http://plnkr.co/edit/kZ2H5pFIibXFwkCk3zEV?p=preview

```
  <div ng-repeat="field in data.fields">
      {{field.name}}: <input ng-model="field.value">
    </div>
```